# How important is PyYAML when deploying in google app engine with Django?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pyyaml

Recently I tried to deploy my django app in google app engine (standard environment - Python version 3.7 - Django version 2.0.3) but I found a problem.

As a previous step to do the deploy I run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

But at the time of deploy this error was generated:

```
Error message: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
  Failed building wheel for PyYAML
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels

error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1.
```

When I realized that the error was due to PyYAML I tried to modify the version in the requirements.txt file, but it didn't work.

As last step I opted to remove PyYAML from my requirements.txt file and in this case it worked. The application is deployed and working.

However my question is: Is there a problem with having deployed without including PyYAML in the requirements.txt?

Comment: Have you tried changing the pyyaml line in the requirements.txt to read `pyyaml==3.13`. There has been a major version number update (5.1) and that might have problems, the 4.2 release of pyyaml had problems as well and had to be retracted. There are wheels for windows available, but not for linux or macOS, so pinning on a good older version of pyyaml might help you out.

Comment: @Anthon the requirements.txt file generated with pip freeze was initially version 3.12 . I tried changing it to 3.13 and 5.1 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be interested, the answer is this:

Google app Engine (standard environment) does not allow to install PyYaml since by default it has it installed:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/

Therefore there is no problem with not add PyYaml in the requirements.txt

PD: it seems that the library PyYaml is added to  requirements.txt file due to the fact that pip is recognizing the yaml file in the folders and determines that it is necessary for the application to work correctly.